# Is possible to change variant on hover MUI card?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Card variant="outline"> Card 1</Card>
```

I want to change card *variant* **outline** to **elevation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here you can see the live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-almeida-gmcucj?file=/src/App.js)

```
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [hover, setHover] = useState('outlined');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card onMouseOver={() => setHover('elevation')} onMouseLeave={() => setHover('outlined')} variant={`${hover}`} style={{height: '200px'}}>Hello How are you</Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you have list of items, you can do like this.

```
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const items = [
    {
      name: "User 1"
    },
    {
      name: "User 2"
    }
  ]
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <Card
        onMouseOver={() => setHover(index)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
        variant={`${hover === index ? 'elevation' : 'outlined'}`}
        style={{ height: "200px" }}
      >
        {item.name}
      </Card>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: in the case of multiple cards (list items) it will work?